# Declaration of ezSQL_mysql::query() should be compatible with ezSQLcore::query()

Tags: php, error-handling, error-reporting, ezsql

I'm just moving from one server to another. My script was working fine on the old server but I started to get this error on the new server:

> "Declaration of ezSQL_mysql::query() should be compatible with
>   ezSQLcore::query()"

This is the first time I see this error and I can't get it fixed. Any help would highly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to include the parameter in the query() function in ezSQLcore, to make it equal to ezSQL_mysq